# Creating individual user profiles

Tags: mysql, node.js, web, user-profile, social-media

I am working on a project and one of the key components is creating customized user profiles. I already have a schema design for the user data that will generate said profile. But I am lost on how the technology works.

I am mostly front-end so it has been sort of overwhelming. The goal is to allow multiple user profile creations and so far I have only seen that this can be achievable via NodeJs or PHP. I have not found any guides.

I am not sure if I am asking the right questions.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's true that you need backend code (in node.js, php, or some other backend language) to accept requests from your front end and handle the creation / update / deletion of records in your MySQL database. Suggest you choose a backend stack (node / express might be good, or php / laravel), then dig up a tutorial or template on user profile creation and authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you already have schema for the user table, I assume you are going to design your own database and backend node.js API to handle user profiles. You may want to build authentication functionalities in the future. If you are not familiar with Node.js yet, I recommend you to start with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/index.htm. It's a good tutorial for beginners.

The whole purpose of a back-end node.js API is building numbers of service with specified route. Once a http request is made to a particular path, it takes parameters and execute some script. In you case the scripts will do something in database containing user profile data, for example, add a row in your data table. This operation is equivalent to creating a new user. Then, the API send response to front-end.

Keep in mind maintaining user profile data is nothing special than regular data. You should be able to pick it up with a couple of days training if you know javascriopt. But if you have to build authentication functionality you need more technologies.

Comment: Well for user authentication, I found that Amazon Cognito is a good option. Along with social media logins. I am trying to learn NodeJs as we speak.